# Conversion from byteArray to decimal for formatted information

Tags: java, arrays, string, hex, data-conversion

I have a byte array that has information in the following format:

```
byte 1 : 0xAA

byte 2 : checksum = XOR

byte 3-20

byte 3- 4 :  unsigned 16-bit, LSB first

byte 5- 6 : Iunsigned 16-bit, LSB first

byte 7- 8 : unsigned 16-bit, LSB first

byte 9-10 : unsigned 16-bit, LSB first

byte 11-12 : unsigned 16-bit, LSB first

byte 13-14 : unsigned 16-bit, LSB first

byte 15-16 : signed 16-bit, LSB first

byte 17-18 : signed 16-bit, LSB first

byte 19-20 : signed 16-bit, LSB first
```

How do I convert it into a decimal format array or just each pair to a decimal?

**Edit**
For example: `AA 20 AD 28 97 31 EE 29 1D 17 6D 1A B4 0D 03 00 F8 FF FA FE` is the direct conversion of the bytearray to hex. Now I want to convert either these hex values or the original bytearray to decimals according to the *given format*.

Comment: byte1*256 + byte2?

Comment: `decimal format array ` What would that be? You should give an example using the values in your byte array.

Comment: @blackapps Remember that Java bytes are signed and that LSB comes first, so `byte1*256 + byte2` doesn't really match the question.

Comment: I know. Just an idea to get started. We like to see some trials from OP first.

Comment: @blackapps convert to decimal format and put it in an array

Comment: What do you mean with decimal format? Please give examples. You start with a byte array where every byte has eight bits. You can display every byte in binary, hexadecimal or decimal notation. The notation does not matter. Its all about the bits. Now tell what kind of new array you wanna have .

Comment: `AA 20 AD 28 97 31 EE 29 1D 17 6D 1A B4 0D 03 00 F8 FF FA FE` So that are twenty values of bytes in hexadecimal notation. Are you telling that (for a start) you cannot make a string with twenty decimal values? Please start with them.

Comment: Or if you have the 16 bit values 31EE or EE31 what it would be in decimal notations? And both in signed and unsigned? Good exercise. Give examples!